# Apache Cordova - Importing JS file from JS file

Tags: cordova

Hello Stack Community,

I want to import a JS file from another JS file.

I tried import like these:

Primary file:

```
import { test } from 'secondary.js' // and without {}

test();
```

Secondary file

```
export function test(){
    alert(1);
}
```

What I got with curly braces
[image: What I got with curly braces]

and without...
[image: and without...]

and tried export module

```
module.exports.test = () => {
alert(1);
}
```

and also tried as that:

```
const { test } = require('secondary.js');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved, when I integrate with Ionic, I can set and import ES6 files.

Comment: Hi there - whilst this was a while ago, I'm now facing the same issue. Can you elaborate on what exactly you did to resolve this ?